# Why does floor division return a float instead of an int

Tags: python, floor, floor-division

```
a = 6
b = 2
c = 9

print(c/b//b)
```

Could anyone tell why is the result of this 2.0 instead of 2?
9/2 = 4.5
4.5//2 should be 2 bcos floor division rounds it to the nearest integer value. But why is the result 2.0?

Comment: `2.0` is the nearest integer value, it just is of type `float`: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html. Also read https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/coerce.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floor division gives round off value. But it necessarily not give an integer. So it depends on the type of operands and as 4.5 is a float value, hence the answer must be a float.
And that's why 4//2 = 2 and 4.5//2 = 2.0

Comment: 2.0 is an integer.

Comment: Not in terms of python ;) It's float there.

Comment: @superbrain it is a `float` object who's value is an integer, in the mathematical sense. `float` objects can represent integers and real numbers

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Meh, they can represent almost no real numbers.